# Magento 2 | Questions regarding taxes

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

With the beginning of the next month there's a reformation of the tax system in the EU and we need to adapt a few critical changes in order to comply with everything. Basically we need to charge the tax percentages of the shipping country at the order (19% for Germany, 25% for Croatia, 20% for Austria, and so on). So far so good, that's possible with the Magento default tax system and shouldn't be a problem at all, but I'm currently looking at a problem that I cannot solve.

---

**Scenario 1** *(A dealer from Austra creates 2 order)*

**Order 1:** Dropshipping to a customer in Austra, therefore no tax should be charged since the dealer's customer is in the main country of the dealer. 0% tax charge - intracommunity order.

**Order 2:** Dropshipping to a customer in Croatia. Since the dealer's customer is not in the main country of the dealer taxes have to be charged, in that case, 25%.

---

How can I configure something like that in Magento? We are running a store based in Germany and sell all over the world. The main point of everything is the following:

- Sales to a customer OR dealer in Germany get taxed 19%
- Sales to a customer within the EU get taxed according to the taxes in the customers country
- Sales to a dealer within the EU AND shipping to the same country as the dealer get NOT taxed
- Sales to a dealer within the EU AND shipping to another country get taxed accordingly to the country where the shipping gets to

---

Hope I can get some help with that.

Comment: just a small suggestion before saving the order  get the country of dealer and also customer's compare them if same no charge and if not charge with respect to saved tax. am i understanding it right or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearification to all,

our tax consultant made a misstake, our dropshipping dealers still havent to pay taxed on our shop, they have to collect them directly from the customer. So its basically working with the default Magento2 tax configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand your question but are you looking for tax calculation based on **shipping address** instead of shipping origin? See: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html

The dealer is your customer, your dealers customer is not your customer, right? So you might have overcomplicated things, but I don't know the tax rules in Germany.

If not; could you elaborate on the exact problem?